# C- How to manipulate processes, child processes and grandchild processes with fork();

Tags: c, process, fork

I want to create an algorithm, utilizing fork(), where one process have to wait for a few seconds then create a child process, after 2 seconds make a second child. Then after another few seconds the first child get a child, making it the first grandchild, and do the same with the second child.

And finally how do I "kill" each one, in this case I want to kill the first and second child at the same time after this "kill" the first grandchild and then the second grandchild.

Basically how to manage processes and how to finish them.

Comment: It is not an algorithm, but a program. And it is operating system specific. I guess you target Linux or Posix. Then read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/). You might use a [process group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_group)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably read a book on Posix programming. 
The rough outline of the code looks like this:

```
if(fork()==0){
   if(fork()==0){

   }else{
      wait()
   }
}else{
  if(fork()==0){
     if(fork()==0){

     }else{
        wait()
      }
  }
   wait()
   wait()
}
```

You should add a couple of sleep() calls to get the waiting behavior you want.

The killing of both grandchilds at the same time is not an easy task. I would approach it with a couple of signal handlers. 
For example, parent sends signals to both child processes, then they execute their "catch" functions, which send a KILL signal to grandchild procecsses.

Comment: Not a book on shell, but a book on Posix programming.